# Frame Buffer Object is black when depth_test is enabled

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, fbo

Im just trying to output the texture created by the FBO to the screen while im walking around the world, so effectively making 2 views of the scene. The problem is anything that is rendered while glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); is on appears as black, if i disable depth test then it works how i want but obviously then I dont have any depth testing.

These are the attachments for my FBO

```
unsigned int WaterFBO::CreateTextureAttachment(int width, int height)
{
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture, 0);
    return texture;
}

unsigned int WaterFBO::CreateDepthTextureAttachment(int width, int height)
{
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texture, 0);
    return texture;
}

unsigned int WaterFBO::CreateDepthBufferAttachment(int width, int height)
{
    unsigned int depthBuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    return depthBuffer;
}
```

and how i create a FBO

```
void WaterFBO::InitRefracBuffer()
{
    refractionFrameBuffer = CreateFrameBufferObject();
    refractionTexture = CreateTextureAttachment(REFRACTION_WIDTH, REFRACTION_HEIGHT);
    refractionDepthTexture = CreateDepthTextureAttachment(REFRACTION_WIDTH, REFRACTION_HEIGHT);
    UnBindCurrentFrameBuffer();
}
```

just found if i comment out the creation of the depth buffer attachment then it also works like depth test is disabled so i guess im creating the depth buffer incorretly?

```
void WaterFBO::InitRefracBuffer()
{
    refractionFrameBuffer = CreateFrameBufferObject();
    refractionTexture = CreateTextureAttachment(REFRACTION_WIDTH, REFRACTION_HEIGHT);
    //refractionDepthTexture = CreateDepthTextureAttachment(REFRACTION_WIDTH, REFRACTION_HEIGHT);
    UnBindCurrentFrameBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Do [`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) for the framebuffer (`refractionFrameBuffer`) and the default framebuffer? Note [`glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56343736/frame-buffer-object-is-black-when-depth-test-is-enabled) doesn't "unbind" the current frambuffer, it binds the default framebuffer 0, that one which is displayed in the window.

Comment: thanks for trying man but that didnt fix it, im at a complete loss ahah, guess ill just continue with no depth testing in the FBOs lol

Comment: "just found if i comment out the creation of the depth buffer attachment then it also works like depth test is disabled so i guess im creating the depth buffer incorretly?" That doesn't follow. If there is no depth buffer, enabling the depth test has no effect whatsoever. Your image getting black when the depth test is enabled actually suggests that the depth buffer is present and working., but something else screwed.

Comment: where is your ```GL::glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) ```

Comment: oh you guys were right. Thank you so much i tried  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) again in a spot that made more sense and it work. cheers guys